# Neo4j Reduce function on relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database that has Players connected to Games through relationships. The relationship has a property playtimeTwoWeeks that I want to use to find out how much time each game was played by any user.

So I have this query

```
MATCH (n:Player)-[p:PLAYS]-(g:Game)
WITH n, p, g
RETURN g, REDUCE(playtime = 0, play IN p | playtime + play.playtimeTwoWeeks) AS total_playtime
```

Which I am not sure it is correct or not, but I can't test it because I get the error

> Type mismatch: expected Collection but was Relationship (line 3,
>   column 40)

Pointing to **p**

I saw some other examples and it seems I am doing the right thing, however I can't figure out what's wrong with the query.

Comment: p is a collection of rels if you use a variable length paths like this: `MATCH (n:Player)-[p:PLAYS*]-(g:Game)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
MATCH (n:Player)-[p:PLAYS]-(g:Game)
WITH n, collect(p) AS plays, g
RETURN g, REDUCE(playtime = 0, play IN plays | playtime + play.playtimeTwoWeeks) AS total_playtime
```

Comment: Thank you, COLLECT() was the function I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need the `WITH` clause in there the way you're using it. I think you can just do something like:

```
MATCH (n:Player)-[p:PLAYS]-(g:Game) 
RETURN g, SUM(p.playtimeTwoWeeks) as total_playtime
```